# How to exclude some endpoints from server.servlet.path configuration?

Tags: spring-boot

I have Spring Boot application with a single `index.html` page.

I need to have `server.servlet.path=/api` setting.

In order to get `index.html` I have to go `localhost:8080/api/` becase of my setting described above.

I want to be able to get `index.html` by `localhost:8080/` and any else endpoints by `localhost:8080/api/**`.

How can I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you configured server.servlet.path=/api, DispatcherServlet is going to handle only request matching URL Patterns /api/**.

One way to achieve your requirement is to use a plain Servlet.

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.util.StreamUtils;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/"})
public class RootServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("static/index.html");
        String content = StreamUtils.copyToString(resource.getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset()  );
        resp.getWriter().write(content);
    }
}
```

Now you can register the Servlet using `@ServletComponentScan` annotation. Assuming you put RootServlet in `com.myapp.servlets` package:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan(basePackages = "com.myapp.servlets")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

For more info see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-add-a-servlet-filter-or-listener